# How to check if a configurable product has customizable options on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, custom-options, custom

I tried to check if a configurable product has custom options and i can't find anything related to this.

I succeed to solve this problem only for the **simple** products using this:

```
$_product->getHasOptions()
```

but this is not working for the **confgiurable** products.

Does anyone know how to do that?